# ts-node error: Could not find a compatible `parseConfigFile` function

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I just install the `ts-node` with `npm install -g ts-node` but I can't execute the REPL, it gives me this error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:478
  throw new TypeError('Could not find a compatible `parseConfigFile` function')
        ^
TypeError: Could not find a compatible `parseConfigFile` function
    at readConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:478:9)
    at Object.register (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:205:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/_bin.ts:136:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
```

I'm using Fedora 27. Any idea?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Fedora problem. I installed `typescript` with `dnf` and `ts-node` with `npm`. To fix I had to uninstall the  `typescript` with `dnf remove -y nodejs-typescript` and reinstall it with `npm i -g typescript`.

The installation commands need root permissions to write to system folders. Now everything works fine. :-)

Regards.